# Comparing all TextBoxes in SortedList

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox

I'm trying to add three Textbox in a SortedList and then to check if they are empty and if they are equal to each other. If that is false than to disable my OK button.

```
var entries = new SortedList<string, int>();
foreach (var textBox in new[] {
  this.txbGroupSeparator,
  this.txbDecimalSeparator,
  this.txbCellDelimiter
})

//this.okButton.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txbCellDelimiter.Text) &&
//    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txbDecimalSeparator.Text) &&
//    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txbGroupSeparator.Text) &&
//    !(this.txbCellDelimiter.Text == this.txbDecimalSeparator.Text) &&
//    !(this.txbCellDelimiter.Text == this.txbGroupSeparator.Text) &&
//    !(this.txbDecimalSeparator.Text == this.txbGroupSeparator.Text);
```

that's my code so far...

Comment: I think you need to add textbox `Text` values to list instead of adding textbox controls

Comment: yes, i think same, but after that ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
var entries = new SortedList<string, int>
{
    { txbGroupSeparator.Text, 0 },
    { txbDecimalSeparator.Text, 1 },
    { txbCellDelimiter.Text, 2 }
};

okButton.Enabled = txbGroupSeparator.Text == txbDecimalSeparator.Text &&
    txbDecimalSeparator.Text == txbCellDelimiter.Text &&
    !txbCellDelimiter.Text.IsNullOrEmpty();
```

First declare and init the `SortedList` with the values, and then enable/disable the button.

Comment: @user3388110 what do you want exactly?

Comment: I have tree textbox and one Button. The Button must dissable if
TextBox Empty are and the text in textbox equal is. but your code didn't work.

Comment: @user3388110 and why you want a `SortedList`?

Comment: That is the task for me to write this tree TextBox in a SortedList and to enable/disable the button by empty and equal textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
   var lstTextValues = new  SortedList<string, string>();
    lstTextValues.Add(this.txbGroupSeparator.Name,this.txbGroupSeparator.Text);
    lstTextValues.Add(this.txbDecimalSeparator.Name,this.txbDecimalSeparator.Text);
    lstTextValues.Add(this.txbCellDelimiter.Name,this.txbCellDelimiter.Text);

    this.okButton.Enabled = true;
    if(lstTextValues.Exists(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value)))
    {
        this.okButton.Enabled = false;

    }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> srtlst in lstTextValues)
    {
        if (lstTextValues.Count(e => e.Value == srtlst.Value) > 1)
        { 
             this.okButton.Enabled = false;
        }
     }
```

Comment: i need SortedList<string, int>();

Comment: @user3388110 you can just change it to int. and the logic below will still work

Comment: @user3388110 checking empty might not work for int. but by keeping it as string your logic is achieved right ?